# sort records by two fields in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

There is a problem (or my misunderstanding) with sorting of records. In my application the data set is loaded by a script, data set contains several records, and all of them have the same `created_at` field. After that, the records are edited/updated manually, so the `updated_at` are different. I'd like to see the most recently non-updated record on top, basically I need to sort the records by two fields, first by `created_at` in reverse oder (old data set go to bottom), then by `updated_at` (already edited records go after non-updated). The model looks like:

```rb
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => "created_at DESC, updated_at"
end
```

After loading two sets of data, I try to get records in the console, the output looks like this:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
>> Part.all.each {|p| puts p.created_at}
2011-07-01 19:52:00 UTC
2011-07-01 19:52:00 UTC
2011-07-01 19:26:44 UTC
2011-07-01 19:26:44 UTC
>> Part.all.each {|p| puts p.updated_at}
2011-07-01 19:52:09 UTC
2011-07-01 19:52:00 UTC
2011-07-01 19:27:15 UTC
2011-07-01 19:33:01 UTC
```

Apparently, the sorting does not work as expected, the expected (desirable) output is:

```
>> Part.all.each {|p| puts p.updated_at}
2011-07-01 19:52:00 UTC
2011-07-01 19:52:09 UTC
2011-07-01 19:27:15 UTC
2011-07-01 19:33:01 UTC
```

I also tried to remove `default_scope` from the model, and run the following works in the console, but it did not help:

```rb
Part.group("created_at").order("updated_at").each {|p| puts p.updated_at}
Part.order("created_at DESC, updated_at").each {|p| puts p.updated_at}
```

Can anybody explain how to achieve the desired order?

UPD: it seems, that the second ordering option is not taken into account simply because the timestamp is stored with higher precision than just seconds, i.e. `created_at` is not `2011-07-01 19:52:00 UTC`, but `2011-07-01 19:52:00.12345 UTC`. consequently, all the records have unique `created_at` timestamp, therefore grouping by this field is not possible. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Should updated_at be sorted descending, too?  Try ordering with `created_at DESC, updated_at DESC`.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. I've tried to set in the model `default_scope :order =>"created_at DESC, updated_at DESC"` and in in the console `Part.order("created_at DESC, updated_at DESC").each {|p| puts p.updated_at}`, both do not give the desired order...